# Plot scatterplot colour specific values present in file

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to highlight values from scatterplot using file which contains values if the values name present in plot and files it should highlight data values in scatter plot how can I achieve my output

Input contains:

```
Model    HP      Av.
Integra  140    15.9
Legend   200    33.9
Century  90     172 
LeSabre  100    172
535i     208    30
Century2 110    15.7
LeSabre2    170 20.8
Roadmaster  180 23.7
```

My code:

```
konA.temp <- log(dat$HP)

konB.temp <- log(dat$Av.)

plot(konA.temp, konB.temp, pch=16, cex=0.4, 
     xlim=c(min(konA.temp, konB.temp), max(konA.temp, konB.temp)), 
     ylim=c(min(konA.temp, konB.temp), max(konA.temp, konB.temp)),
     xlab='log(konA)', ylab='log(konB)')
```

*model-file.txt* without header

```
  Integra
  Legend
  90
  100
  535i
  Century
  Century2
  LeSabre
  Roadmaster
  Riviera
  DeVille
  Seville
  Cavalier
```

I wanted plot scatterplot the common model name present in the file highlight by any color in scatter plot

Comment: I don't understand your problem/question. Could you phrase it differently? Or make an example of your expected output?

Comment: @jay.sf okay I wanted a scatterplot against Hp and av and  highlight the model name in scatter plot which are present in the file. for example just image taken from internet (https://vrzkj25a871bpq7t1ugcgmn9-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/ggplot-scatterplot-with-highlighted-points-600x576.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check if a Model is `%in%` the file and create a `highlight` dummy that is `1` for no match and `2` for a match. Then use a color vector `clr` and subset it with the dummy.

```
dat <- transform(dat, highlight=1+(dat$Model %in% unlist(m.names)))
clr <- c("red", "green")
```

Just do the plot with `with` so that `highlight` dummy can be identified.

```
with(dat,
     plot(log(HP), log(Av.), pch=16, cex=1, 
          xlim=c(min(konA.temp, konB.temp), max(konA.temp, konB.temp)),
          ylim=c(min(konA.temp, konB.temp), max(konA.temp, konB.temp)),
          xlab='log(konA)', ylab='log(konB)', col=clr[highlight]))
```

**Looks like this:**

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=T,  text="Model    HP      Av.
Integra  140    15.9
Legend   200    33.9
Century  90     172 
LeSabre  100    172
535i     208    30
Century2 110    15.7
LeSabre2    170 20.8
Roadmaster  180 23.7")

m.names <- read.table(text="Integra
Legend
90
100
535i
Century
Century2
LeSabre
Roadmaster
Riviera
DeVille
Seville
Cavalier")
```